# installing utorrent server glibc_2.16 not found

Tags: server, glibc, utorrent

I tried nrly everything to fix this problem, but i'm a linux-noob so maybe it's me who does something wrong.

Basicly I get this error_

```
sudo utserver -settingspath /opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3/
utserver: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.16' not found (required by utserver)
```

I tried to install build-essentiels and libssl0.9.8 but it still says glibc2.16 not found.

What can I do to install glibc step-by-step to get utorrent server to work?

Using ubuntu 12.04

THanks for the help and merry christmas everyone!

Comment: you mentioned rpm which is not used by debian based systems. so your question is irrelevant here. ask it on other stackexchange sites.

Comment: Okay it was something I read on other forums, but i'm using ubuntu 12.04.